# Error with Python's virtualenv in terminal

Tags: python, terminal, virtualenv

I am currently attempting to deploy an application to Heroku. One of the first steps is to set up a virtual environment by:

```
virtualenv venv
```

This returns:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenv: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone help me understand what is going on and how I can fix this?

For reference:

```
which python
```

is

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

cd usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7

returns 

-bash: cd: usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: No such file or directory
```

When I `cat virtualenv` I get:

```
#!/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from virtualenv import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

So it references the wrong python(?)

Should I get this to point to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python` ? How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I was actually able to fix this. Here's what I did:

Go to terminal and go to

```
cd /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
```

Open vim and edit the python path to what you see when you run `which python`. Use can use vim for this. Save the file and you are good. Good luck!

Comment: The `cd` is quite superfluous; your editor can open the full path (provided of course you are running with adequate permissions).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on mac so following is not working if you are not on mac.

If you have installed virtualenv prior to using homebrew to install python, it may be your problem.

Try simpler first. Uninstall both virtualenv and python and, again, install python then virtualenv.

And if you still have problem after doing above, check files such as `.bash_profile` if they have right `PATH` values.

This solved my problem, hope you too.